# Avoid Comodo certificates?

Tags: https

We are looking at buying an:

- EV SSL certificate
- Software signing certificate

Comodo seem far cheaper than other providers.  However they seem to have bad press.

Is there any disadvantage to using Comodo certificates?  (I'm thinking along the lines of people not trusting Comodo/blocking anything to do with them).

I'm not looking for recommendations, specifically I want to know if going with Comodo has any actual disadvantage to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comodo is fine. I have been using them for years (both site SSL and code signing) without any problem.

BTW, they recently added one hop into their code signing certification path.